# How to remove space between tr

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am designing an HTML email template,  In the code below, I'm having trouble removing the spacing below the tr removing the space between the tr. I have attached my issue screenshot of how it looks. could you please resolve my issues.

[image]

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            .tablehead {
                max-width: 600px;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            table {
                border: none !important;
            }

            td {
                border: none;
                margin: 0;
            }

            tr {
                border: none;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background:#f3f3f3;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablehead">
                        <tr>
                            <td> <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d9f11059f6e3a8d643a2ec664/images/073fd8e8-1e89-4ec4-9365-5498789b2933.gif" style="width:100%;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d9f11059f6e3a8d643a2ec664/images/e9b50a22-75f0-49a9-af40-ed88dc15ede5.gif" style="width:100%;" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d9f11059f6e3a8d643a2ec664/images/4122dae0-8675-4bbc-8bd3-12dd26627798.jpg" style="width:100%;" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: While I adjust mobile responsive display tr or td space.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) and `margin-bottom` css properties for `img` tag:

```
img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Comment: I added above code but not working could you please adjust responsive below url http://magento.unaux.com/newsletter/?i=1

Comment: @user5561847 It's working fine on the page you give me.

Comment: Only showing that space while adjust responsive mode how to remove this.

Comment: @user5561847 Ahh, I've just tried again by adding `margin-bottom: -1px;` to the `img` tag. It's ok now. Check my updated answer!

Comment: This newsletter template not working minus only working positive value could you please possible another way.

Comment: @user5561847 I wonder how it's not: [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/4grT62n/Screen-Shot-2019-12-25-at-14-12-41.png)

Comment: Newsletter template CSS property minus value (ie margin-top:-1px or padding-top:-2px) anything only working browser but not working in all email app. thanks for your help...

Comment: @user5561847 Fine. Not all of email application accepts css style. Example: With Gmail, these are some css styles which can be accepted: [Gmail Supported CSS Properties & Media Queries](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css). Gmail supports both `vertical-align` and `margin-bottom`. You can search for another applications. Good luck.